# Updating numbericUpdown on runtime in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, numericupdown

I am updating numeric updown on runtime such that I compute a value "x" on runtime and then set the minimum and maximum value of numeric updown.

```
NumUD.Minimum=x/2;
NumUD.Maximum=x;
```

But the problem is that it is not updating. I also tried to call the `update()` and `refresh()` function but still its not working.
Any body who can guide me how to do that.
Thanks

Comment: Where are you writing the given piece of code? Is it getting executed? Did you tried debugging it?

Comment: @NisargShah yes it is executed, I wrote it in a textbox change event..

Comment: should be working fine, unless the code is not executed at runtime

Comment: Just to make sure: What number is `x`, for example, and what value is currently selected in `NumUD`, for example, in one of the situations where you observe `NumUD` is not updating?

Comment: How do you know "it's not updating" ?

Comment: the number is random, sometime it may comes out to be 10,20,30 etc. X is an integer. I always see "0" in the numUD.

Comment: @HenkHolterman because I cant see the updated minimum and maximum :)

Comment: BTW, I suppose your code actually says `Minimum`, not `Mimimun`, right?

Comment: Most Nuds don't actually display Min/Max. But do post actual code, and tag which GUI (WPF, ASP.NET ?)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper yes you are right..

Comment: @HenkHolterman simple .net desktop app on VS2010, c#4.0 expectedly

Comment: Desktop can still be WinForms / WPF / SilverLight .

Comment: @HenkHolterman winforms

Comment: @user1765876 How are you checking that it is not updating?

Comment: @EhsanUllah it is not updating on the GUI, the variables are updating though

Comment: @user1765876 Again i would ask how are you checking on GUI? by inserting values?

Comment: Using the wrong form object reference is a standard mistake.  Add "this.Show();" to your code and you'll probably see it.

Comment: @EhsanUllah yes by changing the value of X

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code and check if the minimum value that is being displayed is set to 10 or not.

```
 int x = 20;
 NumUD.Minimum = x / 2;
 NumUD.Maximum = x;
```

Because i am having a feeling that the value of x must be 0 so you must be having a feeling that the values are not getting set.

Looking to your comments the updated answer would be like this... The below image will show you the actual and needed code.
[image: Revised Answer]

Comment: Is it so that you have set the same thing elsewhere??? something like this...
NumUD.Minimum = 0;
NumUD.Maximum = 0;
Because i dont get any other reason for the same... And i tried the code before posting it...

Comment: Its not the piece of code, its just providing values in the propery bar of control

Comment: @user1765876 your problem is not clear, you said `it's not updating` and I understand that `it here is your numeric updown`, however `numericupdown` has some properties to care about, so could you point it out exactly which property is not updating?

Comment: @KingKing the property minimum and maximum is updating but the result is not reflected in the GUI

Comment: @user1765876 still not clear, what's the result? You have some code to show `Minimum` and `Maximum` on your GUI? Or you want your the value of your `numericupdown` to be between the new range defined by the newly updated `Minimum` and `Maximum`? For example, the current value of your `numericupdown` is 7, the new `Minimum` and `Maximum` are 1 and 5 respectively and you want the current value to be changed to `5` (the `Maximum`)?